# Netbios name query not working

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, scapy, netbios

Recently I have started working on my new python project of mine in which I would like to include something that takes an ip address and converts it to a netbios name,
So by using scapy I tried executing the following piece of code:

sr(Ether() / IP(flags=0x02, dst = '10.0.0.0') / UDP(sport=RandShort()) / NBNSQueryRequest(NAME_TRN_ID=0x8228, QUESTION_NAME= '*', QUESTION_TYPE='NBSTAT') )

But so far with no success.....

Does anybody have an idea of how to make this work???

Answer (score 0):

The first mistake I can see in your code is that you are using `sr()` **and** provide the `Ether` layer. You can either use `srp()`, or let Scapy deal with the `Ether` layer.

Also, since you expect only one packet, you can use `sr1()` or `srp1()` that should return the first answer it gets.

And, you are targeting what could be a network IP, not a host IP. Here is something you could try:

```
sr1(IP(dst='10.0.0.1') /
       UDP(sport=RandShort()) /
       NBNSQueryRequest(NAME_TRN_ID=0x8228, QUESTION_NAME= '*', QUESTION_TYPE='NBSTAT'))
```